# can I call subclasses on an array of a superclass?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have an array of an object that has subclasses, can I access methods in the subclasses through calling the array?

This is a method in my **Banking** class, I would like to set the checking:

```
public void deposit() throws IOException {
BufferedReader br;
String entered_amount;

System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit? :");
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
entered_amount = br.readLine();
double amount = Double.valueOf(entered_amount).doubleValue();
balance = balance + amount;

System.out.println("Your balance is: " + getBalance());
```

Here is my **Checking** class:

```
public class Checking extends Bankaccount {

private double balance;

public Checking() {
}

public Checking(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

/**
 * @return the balance
 */
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

/**
 * @param balance the balance to set
 */
public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

}

When calling `baArray[0]` in my main class is there a way to make deposit set the value of balance within the checking class?

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm writing out the array of objects to a file and rereading them when the program starts. I need to be able to store 3 sets of checking and savings. My deposit method would be what i'm trying to edit to use inheritance to set the balance in checking.

Comment: As long as the superclass declares a public `deposit` method, there will be no problem. The method may be abstract.

Comment: Exactly what afk5min said.  You'll want to make the super class have a no-body method `deposit` which the sub classes provide the appropriate logic for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `Banking` class:

```
public abstract setBalance(double balance);
```

If you have `subclasses` of `Banking` besides the `Checking` class for which a `setBalance` method doesn't make sense, then you can implement the method and simply have it throw an exception.  (It would seem to make sense for a `Savings` class to also have a `setBalance` method though.)

Alternatively, you can just move `Checking`'s `setBalance` method up to the superclass `Banking`, then `Checking` and `Savings` will both inherit the `setBalance` method.  If you need to override them, you can, no problem.

EDIT: As per the comments to this answer, it's now more clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

If you're intending to have an array of `Banking` objects, and each object has some unique account number, and for every `Bank` account, there is a `Checking` account and a `Savings` account, then logically, it sounds like it makes more sense for `Checking` and `Savings` to be `private` classes that can only be accessed through the `Banking` class.

So when an account holder goes to the bank, they open a `Banking` account.  Perhaps by default this comes with 1 `Checking` account and 1 `Savings` account.  These would be class variables in your `Banking` class:

```
private Checking checking;
private Savings savings;
```

Now your `Banking` class needs public methods to access the checking and savings accounts.

Let's say your `Checking` and `Savings` class both have a `getBalance` and `setBalance`.  Now your `Banking` class would need a `setter` & `getter` for each type of account, and it just calls the appropriate method.

For example, in your `Banking` class:

```
public void setCheckingBalance(double balance)
{
    checking.setBalance(balance);
}

public double getCheckingBalance()
{
    return checking.getBalance();
}
```

Then in your main method, you'll use these methods via:

```
baArr[0].setCheckingBalance(100.00);
```

Comment: can you explain what public abstract setBalance(double balance); does? and hows to use it? is that going to set checking balance? I believe thats an interface? i dont know Im unfamiliar with them.

Comment: `abstract` simply means that the method doesn't actually exist in the class it's written in (you can't call it on any object of `Banking` class if you instantiate a `Banking` object).  BUT, any subclass of `Banking` MUST implement a `setBalance` method.  So when you call it on an array of `Banking` objects, it knows they'll all have this method, and it will look into the right class for the method to call polymorphically.

Comment: could I make an abstract of set and get balance?

Comment: Yep.  You can make an `abstract` of any method.  You could even make `Banking` an `abstract class` if that makes sense for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm confused, so if i put this in if i call baArray[0].setBalance(double) it will pass to the checking method? and what if i have checking and a savings method how does it distingish between the two setBalance() methods in checking and savings @nhgrif

Comment: It will look to see whether the object at index 0 of your array is a `Checking` or `Savings` object and call the appropriate method.  It does this at run time.  It's called `dynamic binding`.

Comment: I'm confused, baArray[0] is suppose to receive an account id, and store a checking and savings account. but it can only be a checking or savings?

Comment: it hit home when you said override. Thank you!